# Automapper with nested entity not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have two classes which are mentioned below. I am trying to map those through Auto Mapper but it is not working.

```
  public class VMTemplates
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VMTemplateGroup> VMTemplateGroup { get; set; }
}

  public VMTemplateViewModel()
    {
        VMTemplateGroup = new List<VMTemplateGroupViewModel>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Upload File")]
    [Display(Name = "Upload File")]
    [ValidateFile]
    public HttpPostedFileBase TemplateUpload { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public List<VMTemplateGroupViewModel> VMTemplateGroup { get; set; }
```

I am using this code to map them

```
     confi.CreateMap<VMTemplateViewModel, VMTemplates>().ReverseMap();
            confi.CreateMap<VMTemplateGroupViewModel, VMTemplateGroup>().ReverseMap();
```

calling code

```
 public VMTemplates GetVMTemplateById(int id)
    {
        return DataContext.VMTemplates.Include("VMTemplateGroup").Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

This is where exception happens. I get stack overflow exception

```
   public VMTemplateViewModel GetVMTemplateById(int templateId)
    {
        var result = _vmTemplateRepository.GetVMTemplateById(templateId);


        return _autoMapperService.MapEntity<VMTemplateViewModel>(result);
    }
```

Comment: why do you mean by not working? have you tried adding try catch? is there any error? are some of the properties not mapping or all of them? could you post the line of code you are mapping ?

Comment: "I am using this code to map them"...that code just creates the mapping rule. Please also show how you actually perform the mapping when you have a specific instance of the objects. There are a few different ways to do it, so it might be significant. Also, do you get any errors or exceptions? Normally if automapper fails to map something it throws an exception.

Comment: It says stack overflow exception. I have added calling code in the question

Comment: Try upgrading. If that doesn't solve it, make a proper repro.

Comment: What type is `_autoMapperService`? What is `result` populated with?

Comment: This link resolved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251043/automapper-throwing-stackoverflowexception-when-calling-projecttot-on-iquery